# Javascript RPG game

Tags: javascript

I am a complete novice when it comes to using javascript. I have been told a good way to learn is make a simple RPG game and then build on it as my knowledge increases. The concept is very simple. I want the user to select the direction they need to go in and then be presented with 2 doors and then something happens behind the door. So far I have been trying to do this using if statements with prompts and alerts but it just keeps looping through all the options. Does anybody know how to get it to stop displaying all outcomes, regardless of what the input is?

```
{
  userinput = prompt('Enter direction (North,East,South,West or Q)', 'Q');

  // ********** Go North ******************
  if (userinput == 'North')
    prompt('Would you like to go down Hole 1 or Hole 2?'); {
    if (userinput == 'Hole 1');
      alert('You have found food for your family');
    if (userinput == 'Hole 2');
      alert('You have been eaten by a fox');
  }
  }
```

Comment: you aren't reassigning `userinput`.

Comment: you should try to save the second prompt result in `userinput`

Comment: What do you mean by "Stop this"? Also, asking for another way to do it is too broad and not a good fit for SO, you should [edit] it out. Your foxes are brutal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `prompt` statement does not assign anything to `userinput`.  Try this:

```js
{
  userinput = prompt('Enter direction (North,East,South,West or Q)', 'Q');

  // ********** Go North ******************
  if (userinput === 'North')
    userinput = prompt('Would you like to go down Hole 1 or Hole 2?'); {
    if (userinput === 'Hole 1') {
      alert('You have found food for your family');
    } else {
      if (userinput === 'Hole 2') {
        alert('You have been eaten by a fox');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that makes sense now. The only issue I am having is that once i select hole 1 or hole 2, it will display the outcome for hole 1 then hole 2 regardless. I'm trying to get it so that if the input is hole 1, an alert pops up with text and then it returns back to 'what direction you would like to go'.

Comment: That's why my example added braces and `else` statements.  You also had semicolons after your `if` statements.  These will serve as the body of the `if`, so that explains why you were always seeing each message.

Comment: Yes thank you for clearing that up. I spent ages trying to use if else but I had it laid out all wrong, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No worries and welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you 'thank' people by accepting their answer and/or upvoting...